# How to get the filesystem name and size in C?

Tags: c, filesystems

I'm passing a file or a directory to my Unix C program and I want to determine to what file system it belongs to and what is the size of that system. I've tried using `getmntent()` from `mntent.h` and some functions from `fstab.h` but to no luck. Is there any way to do at all?

Edit:
What I meant by no luck is that for example when using `getmntent()` the mnt_type field was empty. I used it like this:

```
struct mntent* storage = getmntent(fopen(argv[1], "r"));
if(storage) printf("File system type: %s\n", storage->mnt_type);
```

and using `fstab.h` always returned NULL.

EDIT 2:

```
struct statvfs* statisticVfs = malloc(sizeof(struct statvfs));
rtrn = statvfs(argv[1], statisticVfs);
if(rtrn != -1)
{
    printf("Block size: %lu\n", statisticVfs->f_bsize);
    FILE* myFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(myFile) puts("Opened!");
    struct mntent* storage = getmntent(myFile);
    if(storage) printf("Type: %s\n", storage->mnt_type);
}
else puts("Error when using statvfs!");
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of what you have tried, and tell us *how* it didn't work. What result did you get? What did you expect? Also please take some time to refresh [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: What operating system?  File names and filesystems are operating system-specific.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Linux. More specifically Gentoo x64

Comment: @Hulk yes. That is done before the code snippet that I've provided here.

Comment: @KapitaiN Is that prior `fopen()` closed before this?  Recommend to `NULL` check this `fopen()` too.  When code fails, no time to scrimp on error checking.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica currently made it so that there is only 1 `FILE*` in the function (meaning there's only 1 `fopen()`) and it is valid, I've checked it. Yet the `mnt_type` field is still empty.

Comment: @KapitaiN, curious, is `errno==0` afterward?  We really need a [mcve]

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, just checked. Errno is still 0. Added the full code needed to understand the problem in the second edit.

Comment: I take it `"Opened!"` was printed.  If not, code is UB as `struct mntent* storage = getmntent(myFile);
    if(storage) printf("Type: %s\n", storage->mnt_type);` should be part of the above `if()`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes, "Opened!" was indeed printed. I really see no reason why would the `mnt_type` field be left out empty. Unless I misunderstand the `mntent.h` library somehow.

Comment: By "empty", do you mean `NULL` or `""`?

Comment: Tip: for debugging potentially _empty_, use to use sentinels (like <>) to help notice beginning/trailing white-space.  `printf("Type: <%s>\n", storage->mnt_type ? storage->mnt_type : "myNULL");`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica got "Type: <>" as a result. That means it's just an empty string.

Comment: "but to no luck."  Does that mean output is not presented the expected block size too?  Or is the problem just about the filesystem name?  Perhaps all is fine and the file system name is `""`.  Good luck - I likely cannot advance this more.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes, the other variables are fine. I've never encountered an unnamed file system. If that's the case then, that's a new one for me. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mimic the behavior of the coreutil's [stat](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/stat.c) command (Eg: `stat -f -c "Blocks:%b Type:%T" $FILENAME`) to get the information. It essentially does a `statfs(2)` on the file and parses the details. You can compare the `(statfsbuf->f_type)` with the list of cases and get the filesystem type. See the listing for `stat.c` to understand what it does.

Comment: Sadly the `f_type` field is unavailable to me.

Comment: @KapitaiN How come? Aren't you using (Gentoo) Linux?

Comment: I am and this is what I'm getting: https://imgur.com/a/kjScXUT

Comment: @KapitaiN That's `statvfs` and not `statfs`. Is this a homework question?

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. Is there an easy way to compare the field to the cases as there are so many of them? And no this is not a homework question, I'm learning C by myself.

Comment: No, you would need to enumerate through all possible values. Okay, if this helped, please accept the answer.